# How do I manage name spaces in a Spring Integration project with multiple flows

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration project that has several flows (some where between 10-15). I would like to keep my namespace clean since several flows might have similar sounding components (for ex - several flows might have a channel named *fileValidatorChannel*). I think I have a couple of different options to keep names from colliding with each other:

A. Preface every component name with the flow that it belongs to. For ex - flowAFileValidatorChannel, flowBFileValidatorChannel, etc
B. Create a context hierarchy where every flow is it's own context and every flow inheriting from a master context where all the common beans/sub-flows are.

What's the better approach? Is there are better way to keep my name space clean?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest your problem isn't clear.

Any Spring Integration component is a bean finally. So, their ids are just to distinguish them from other bean.

Let's imaging if you don't have Spring Integration in your application. So, you would worry about some clean naming strategy for all your beans anyway?

From other side consider to use [Spring Integration Flow](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow) project:

> The goal is to support these, and potentially other semantics while providing better encapsulation and configuration options. Configuration is provided via properties and or referenced bean definitions. Each flow is initialized in a child application context. This allows you to configure multiple instances of the same flow differently.